# How to add files to repository using svn.exe

Tags: svn

I need to add new file to the Apache Subversion repository.

I am using SVN 1.7.6 on Windows 7 and the following command:

```
svn.exe add <path>
```

Path means *repository path* or *working copy path*?

Comment: LOL RTFM: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html and http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.html

Comment: just look this http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/programs/SVN/svn.html

Answer (score 0):

Working copy already 'knows' repository path it's associated with.

The `svn add` command requires you to enter path to a file or folder you want to **add** to Subversion (i.e. to your working copy). See command-line reference at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html

Answer (score 0):

```
cd C:\myrepo

svn add myfile
```

or

```
svn add mydir\myotherdir\myfile
```

See reference [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html)

Comment: "C:\SVN\svn-win32-1.7.6\bin>svn.exe add C:/Files/out.txt"                                                                                Its showing Error "svn: E155007: 'C:\Files' is not a working copy"